# How do I display an image or slideshow of a few images while hovering/clicking text? (Ex. image attached below)

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I display an image or slideshow of a few images while hovering/clicking text?

Here's where I'm at right now:

1. I have professional experience in graphic design, so creating svg's is not an issue.
2. I am a beginning web developer, and to be honest have no clue what I am doing when it comes to anything javascript, and only have the bare minimum of understanding when it comes to html/css.

My goal:

I am trying to display an image (or slideshow-if possible), whenever the user either hovers or clicks on certain text. I've attached an example below. If you would like to further understand the interactivity of the text and what I am trying to do, click [here](https://cwitmer34.github.io/aboutme.html).

[Image popup example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFoI3.png)

**Edit:** Changed the word 'highlights' to 'hover' for correct interpretation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This question is understandable but please try referring to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask next time. Also, please mention your efforts and code.

Comment: @BlindSpot thank you for the advice! I will use that next time, sorry. I currently have no code for this as I have no idea how to even go about a problem like this yet since I am a beginner (talking about a week or so into learning html/css/js).

Comment: No problem, I still have solution for you :) It may take me somewhile to post it.

Comment: Sweet. No time restraints for me, I'm on your personal time so don't stress it.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, it took some while to figure out some things. Also, in example I have posted at end, I use clip-path to create arrow, so editing the tooltip element may not work as desired. You may remove clip-path and find an alternative if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to implement is called as tooltip. You just want a custom tooltip. I made it my own way, but it requires JavaScript,

1. Add class `tooltiptext` to the element, you want to add hover effect to.
2. Just below the element, add the tooltip element inside the div and add it to `tooltip` class, like this:

```html
<span class="tooltiptext">text that will be hovered for effect</span>

   <div class="tooltip">This is a tooltip</div>
```

**NOTE:**  Tooltip must be exactly below the element to work, if there's any element in between them, it won't work.

3. Add CSS:

```css
/*Position and style the tooltip element"*/
.tooltip {
 top: 0%;
 padding: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: grey;
 clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 6px), 55% calc(100% - 6px), 50% 100%, 50% 100%, 45% calc(100% - 6px), 0 calc(100% - 6px));
 clip-path: inset(01 round 0 0 -5% -5%);
 box-shadow: 0 -6px 0 2px #fff inset, 0 0 0 2px #fff inset;
}

/*When "tooltiptext" is hovered, act on the immediate next div element with class "tooltip"*/
.tooltiptext:hover+div.tooltip {
 display: block;
}
```

4. Finally, to precisely position the tooltip according to coordinates of parent element, add JS:

```js
//get all elements with class "tooltiptext"
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltiptext");

//Next, get all elements with class "tooltip"
var tooltips = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip");

//iterate through all the elements of class "tooltiptext"
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {

  //get the distance of the current element, which loop is iterating through
  let distance = elements[i].getBoundingClientRect();

  //set the left position of tooltip at same position(just below) as parent element according to the x-coordinate
  tooltips[i].style.left = distance.x - 55 + "px";

  //set the top position of tooltip at same position(just below) as parent element according to the x-coordinate
  tooltips[i].style.top = distance.y - 140 + "px";
}
```

Here's a working example, you can check:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltiptext");
var tooltips = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip");
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
  let distance = elements[i].getBoundingClientRect();
  tooltips[i].style.left = distance.x - 55 + "px";
  tooltips[i].style.top = distance.y - 140 + "px";
}
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(24, 24, 24);
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.tooltiptext {
  color: #38ac85;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.tooltip {
  top: 0%;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 6px), 55% calc(100% - 6px), 50% 100%, 50% 100%, 45% calc(100% - 6px), 0 calc(100% - 6px));
  clip-path: inset(01 round 0 0 -5% -5%);
  box-shadow: 0 -6px 0 2px #fff inset, 0 0 0 2px #fff inset;
}

.tooltiptext:hover+div.tooltip {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body style="text-align:center;">
  <br><br>
  <h3>This is an example, hover over the button below to see magic!</h3>

  <br><br>

  <span>So this is an example text and you can hover over </span><span class="tooltiptext">cats</span>
  <div id="t1" class="tooltip"><img src="http://placekitten.com/120/80"><br>Cats</div>
  <span> to see the effect. In case, you don't like cats hover over </span><span class="tooltiptext">dogs</span>
  <div id="t2" class="tooltip"><img src="https://placedog.net/120/90"><br>Dogs</div>
  <span> instead to see the effect.</span>

  <br><br>
</body>

</html>
```